# Encryption and Decryption in salesforce

Tags: apex, encryption

It is working for some records it is showing up the above error for some records

it showing up the following error

> Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Encryption

```
string lid=l[0].id+'';
String key1 = Label.PWV_CryptoKey;
Blob Key = Blob.valueOf(key1);
Blob data = Blob.valueOf(lid);
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);
String b64Data = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
string leaURL =Label.PWV_FavoriteURL+'lid='+b64Data;
l[0].Encrypted_URL__c =leaURL;
```

Decryption:

```
 String key1 = Label.PWV_CryptoKey;
 Blob Key = Blob.valueOf(key1);
 oid=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oId');
 Blob data = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(oid);
 Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);
 String decryptedDataString = decryptedData.toString();
```

Comment: I guess issue can be when you are encrypting you are using key as string lid=l[0].id+'' .A blank string is adding while decoding you are just getting value from URL parameter .Turn on your logs and debug oid for failures

Comment: I removed and i checked it but still i am displaying with the same error

Comment: can you debug with logs .So the error is clear the key is in multiple of 16 bytes

Comment: VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [101]|Key|BLOB(16 bytes)

Comment: In debug log i found this VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [101]|Key|BLOB(16 bytes)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the value passed in parameter `oId` is the value you encoded? You should add debugging to check that. (The encoding code you posted appears to be using a parameter named `lid`.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Difference is my encrypted id is contains symbols and in the browser the symbols are changed to "%"

Which is differentiating the Encrypted URL

So Currently i am using base64 to encrypt and decrypt

Comment: This suggestion should be considered actively harmful. Base64 encoding, as the name suggests, refers only to character encoding. This is absolutely not even remotely the same thing as encryption.

Comment: Are you encoding in Base64 _after_ encrypting your ID?

Comment: Topic starter put his code into question

Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);
String b64Data = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);

Answer (score -1):

Crypto.encrypt() takes one of the parameters as "initializationVector". That always needs to be 16 characters. Else it will give this error

Comment: The OP is using `Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV()`, not `Crypto.encrypt()`. They do not have to create their own initialization vector.